# crystalreport viewer do not work async on loading pages

Tags: .net, asynchronous, crystal-reports, load

I have a stored procedure resource that returns some data as a report source in crystal report.
When I'm designing the report in CrystalReports11 Software it loads pages asynchronously and I can see first page immediately and seeing next pages loading but when I'm using it's .Net Control on a form, it loads all data first and all pages (Seems to be freezed) then shows first page.
How can I load report in async mode so that I can immediately view first page?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is something that can be controlled. I have actually not been able to confirm your scenario. Whenever I run a report in CR it loads the report completely before displaying it. The only difference I can see is if there is a subreport within the report. The main report will load and CR will display the report while the subreport may still be loading (which you will see at the bottom of the screen). In the Viewer the main report and subreport will load completely before anything gets displayed.
Now in the Microsoft Report Viewer you can set asynchronous rendering, which is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252090%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). I'm not aware that you can do that for Crystal. What you could do is some sort of workaround. You could try and get the total amount of pages first and then call the report which would make it pretty fast. See the very last post in this [thread](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?563378-Crystal-Report-Viewer-performance-issues) for some code and see if that might help you.